# How to open a file from browser by using asp.net c# code

Tags: asp.net, file, filesystems

From Service method return me:

```
String FileName,
Byte[] FileData, 
string FileType( includes:  doc, pdf, tif, tiff, gif, jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, wpd)
```

How can I generate a file based on filetype and show it to user in browser? Download to user is ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// You will need to figure out the correct content type based on the file type 
// for example image/jpeg for jpeg files
Response.ContentType = ...;
var cd = new ContentDisposition()
{
    Inline = true,
    FileName = FileName
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(FileData, 0, FileData.Length);
```

Comment: To be complete I would add a Response.Flush() and Response.Close() after the Write.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml) is the complete list of common MIME types.